# SharePoint Online - New Item attach files from users network drive or UNC path based of column data

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, smb

I'm not sure if this is possible, I would like when users create a New Item in SharePoint Online list in one of the columns/fields that when they enter text/code it will go out to the LAN and attach those files to the item. The network folder path will be the same + the code they entered. For Example if they enter in the code field text box "TRENT123", then the contents of the network folder at UNC path \server\files\TRENT123\ will be attached to that item.

Thanks!
Trent.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to either build a remote event receiver via a SharePoint add-in or use webhooks.  In both cases, when an item is created/updated, they'll get triggered and you can run some logic.  As for accessing a network folder... I think you may need to map the network folder to you Azure Storage.  I'm not sure that you can or should reach down into your LAN for files.  It's probably easier to just get them from a mapped Azure Storage.

Here are some resources.

Remote event receivers:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/create-a-remote-event-receiver-in-sharepoint-add-ins

Webhooks:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/webhooks/overview-sharepoint-webhooks